# How to prevent the "ApplicationDestinations" (Jump Lists maximum entries) Windows registry key from getting reset?

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot, windows-registry, jumplist

The Windows (7) registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ApplicationDestinations`

controls the maximum number of items that can appear in a Windows Jump List (AKA jumplist).

By default, it contains a `dword` named `MaxEntries` with a decimal value of 8.

Because this limit is low, I wrote a small batch file that runs when Windows boots that changes it to 15 (decimal).  This works as expected.

The issue is that, often within 6 hours of booting (but not always), that `dword` in the Windows registry gets reset to the default value of 8.

It's most likely a Windows process that is resetting the value.

What can be done to keep that Windows registry key from getting reset?

Bonus points if you know what Windows process is causing it to get reset.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what process, but often, you can prevent modification of a registry key by denying yourself `Set Value` permission after you've set the key to its desired value.

1. Right-click the key in question
2. Select `Permissions...`
3. Click `Advanced`
4. If you aren't currently the owner or have "Full Control", you will need to take ownership of the key before adding an entry.
   [image]
5. Click `Add`
6. Click `Select a principal`, type your username, and click `OK`
   [image]
7. Select `Deny` for the Type
8. Click `Show advanced permissions` and select `Set Value`
   [image]
   [image]
9. If you had to take ownership, restore ownership to the original owner
10. `OK` your way out

Comment: Wow. That's real clever. Thank you.  After step 5, I don't see a `Select a principal` option.  I see a dialog box with `Object Types...`, `Locations...`, `Check Names`, and `Advanced...` buttons (as well as `OK` and `Cancel`).  It also has a text entry field entitled `Enter the object name to select`.  How do you recommend proceeding?

Comment: That's the dialog displayed when you click `Seelct a principal`.  Screenshots added. Hope they help. Thanks for the typo corrections -- my left hand gets ahead of my right when typing and impaired vision thwarts my best efforts at proofreading!

Comment: Oh wow.  That looks super helpful.  Thank you so much.  I'm at the wrong machine right now, but as soon as I'm on the right box, I'll follow your updated instructions.  And one hand acting different than the other is a familiar situation.  One of my hands knows exactly where it is, whereas the other has a mind of its own. ;)

Comment: Cool. Will be on the lookout for an update from you.

Comment: Hi Keith. I finally had some time to work on this.  My dialog boxes were a bit different, but I used your technique, and we'll see if the desired value sticks.  I did things slightly differently than you recommended, and I would like your feedback.  Instead of adding a new `deny` permission, I simply edited the existing `allow` permission.  Windows created a new `deny` permission as a result, so I'm thinking the outcome was identical.  What do you think?